# Tableau won't import csv

Tags: csv, tableau-api

I am using Tableau 10.5 and I am trying to import csv data which is a basic step. But for some reason it won't, it just says 'Loading Data' with the icon spinning round and round. The csv file is quite small too.

Comment: This seems more relevant to [su]

Comment: What OS? Does it work with earlier versions of Tableau? Tableau 10.5.0 introduced Hyper which promises great performance improvements, but also introduced major changes to how CSV and Excel are handled.

Comment: It is Mac OS 10 (High Sierra). I have noticed that Tableau 10.5 imports CSVs correctly for Windows 7 but not for my Macbook.

Comment: I have the same problem on my Mac, and submitted a support ticket to Tableau -- thought it might be something I installed with home-brew that conflicted. Suggest submitting a ticket also and citing ticket #03546321

Comment: I have installed 10.4 on my Mac and it works now, it seems to be a problem with 10.5

Comment: Please submit a support ticket to Tableau. I see the same problem.

Comment: @Peter Zhang - see new answer for a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Tableau 10.5.0 on my Mac.

Tableau support said it was a bug in their app that will be fixed in a subsequent release. In the meantime, they provided the following workaround which solved the problem for me.

Add the following lines to /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
::1 localhost
```

You can remove the lines from /etc/hosts when Tableau releases a version that fixes the bug, but it probably doesn't do harm if you don't.

You may need to edit that file as an administrator using a text editor like vi in Terminal.app or ITerm2.app if you don't see it in the Finder Browser.